Lstlisting: check if style exists
I need to find a way to define a lstlisting style only if it was not previously defined, but I can't find how to check if a style has been previously defined or not. How could I do that?
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{}
\iftrue %%%% What can I put here?
\message{Is defined}
\else
\message{Is not defined}
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
Foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


You can check for the existence of \lststy@<style>$ using an \ifcsname...\endcsname conditional clause. Specifically,
% Check if mystyle is defined (via \lstdefinestyle)
\ifcsname lststy@mystyle$\endcsname
  \message{mystyle is defined^^J}
\else
  \message{mystyle is not defined^^J}
\fi

would work. Unfortunately, \lstdefinestyle acts like a \def on the macros it creates, overwriting content as needed.
